# C: Why passing a float/double literal for an int argument does not raise warnings?

Tags: c, linux, gcc-warning

Consider this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    sleep(.1);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with `gcc -Wall sleep.c -o sleep` with no warnings.
Running it gives me

```
time ./sleep

real    0m0,001s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,000s
```

`.1` magically becomes `0`, but my question is why no warnings?
I'm using stock gcc 7.3.0 in Lubuntu 18.04

Comment: I get `warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int' changes value from 0.1 to 0`. By the way that's indeed a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: `-Wconversion` isn't enabled by `-Wall`; you need to ask for that specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a valid conversion - the fractional part is discarded when you convert it `0.1` to `unsigned int`. It's essentially equivalent to `sleep(0);`. So a compiler is not required to issue any diagnostics.

However, `gcc` does have an option [`-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) which produces:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion a.c

    a.c: In function ‘main’:
    a.c:8:11: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘unsigned int’ changes value from ‘1.0000000000000001e-1’ to ‘0’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
         sleep(0.1);
               ^~~
```

Comment: ... and the language specifies that this particular conversion is among those that are performed implicitly in this context, provided that a (correct) prototype for `sleep()` is in scope.  There are other potential conversions that are *not* performed implicitly.

Comment: It does as `<unistd.h>` (which provides `sleep`'s prototype) is included.

Comment: Yes.  The main point of my previous comment is in its last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

C automatically does this. If you put a decimal, such as double or float, into an int, short, long, etc, what you get is the truncated number. That is, all decimals dropped off.
3.3 becomes 3, 5.7 becomes 5, and so on.